# Evaluating data into a repeater from a Repository

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to assign data to a repeater from a databind in the .cs file. I have been out of the ASP and C# game in terms of databinding for a while and have completely forgotten the basics.

```
public partial class Project : System.Web.UI.Page {
IUnitOfWork unitofwork = new UnitOfWork();
    IProjectRepository _projectRepo = null;
    IProjectRepository Projects
    {
        get
        {
            if (_projectRepo == null)
                _projectRepo = new ProjectRepository(unitofwork);
            return _projectRepo;
        }
    }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
        }

        var projectId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ProjectId"]);
        var projectTask = Request.QueryString["ProjectStatus"];

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            currentProject = Projects.GetByExpression(p => p.ID == projectId).FirstOrDefault();
            currentProject = Projects.GetByExpression(p => p.Status == projectTask).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

What is the best way to go about assigning the data to the repeater. The repeater is a basic table format if that is important information for anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repeaters are no different than `GridViews` or `DropDownLists`, etc. All you need to do is gather the data, Set the DataSource and then call DataBind().

For example:

```
var data = rep.GetData();
repeater.DataSource=data;
repeater.DataBind();
```

The repeater itself must have markup code to define how the data is to be bound. For example:

```
<asp:Repeater id="cdcatalog" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:TextBox id="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("SomeProperty")%>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Neat, sweet, and complete!  +1